# Slope of VTC for FET

Tags: fet

The book we are reading states that the maximum slope of this graph occurs at B, but I cannot understand from this graphic how that is possible. It appears to me the maximum magnitude of slope occurs at Q because it is closer to being vertical, which is infinite slope. How is this the case?

[image: VTC of FET]

[image: Desciption]

[image]

Comment: Is it for a push-pull output stage? What does VTC stand for?

Comment: Voltage transfer characteristic of a mosfet. The circuit is just a biased mosfet with a small signal superimposed and a drain resistance. The source is grounded. I will edit with a picture.

Comment: Looks like the book is wrong to me.

Comment: What book is it and is it the latest edition AND have any errata documents been produced?

Comment: It's Microelectronic Circuits by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition. There is an eighth edition that I believe just came out, but this is a book series that has been around for a while. Also, the whole basis of the \$A_{Vmax}\$ is very important so I'm assuming it's right, I just don't know how.

Comment: It’s clearly wrong in one respect or the other. Check for errata.

Comment: I checked errata and couldn't find anything about it. How very bizarre.

Comment: I agree so maybe you found something new to report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure is drawn incorrectly.  The written words and equations are accurate.  A full explanation is available here:  https://dfdeboer.github.io/errata/Sedra_Smith/7th/S_S_7_ER.HTM#P374B (I am the author of that Web page.)  Kudos to the OP for an observant eye to tie those details together!